# Diode and resistor in parallel

Tags: power-supply, voltage, resistors, diodes, parallel

I was recently investigating a model of a circuit in which there is a resistor in parallel with a forward-biased diode.

Why is the current passing through the resistor dictated solely by the forward voltage of the diode? Why doesn't the resistor 'see' the supply voltage?

For reference,

- Resistor: 1000 ohm
- Diode: 0.6V forward voltage
- Supply voltage: 40V

Comment: add the power supply internal resistance to your circuit

Comment: I'm not from an electrical background - could you advise on what I should expect to see? Given that the forward voltage of the diode is small compared to the voltage entering this part of the circuit (40V) - I would've thought that the diode's effect would be relatively minor.... is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: It is wrong to say that it is "dictated." The correct way to say it is to say that the voltage across the resistor and the voltage across the diode are the same, but they are trivially the same by definition of the word "parallel." There is no magic force or secret channel of communication. It is kind of like saying "why is the speed of the tow vehicle dictated entirely by the speed of the trailer?" There is no dictation. They are just coupled directly together so the speed is the same.

Comment: The diode gets to decide what will be the voltage drop across its terminals and hence that across the resistor because it was parallel to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic electrical knowledge: two devices in parallel always experience the same voltage drop.

If you connect a diode and a resistor in parallel, their forward voltages must be the same. And since the diode has a pretty much fixed forward voltage, this is the forward voltage that they both will have.

So the current through the 1 kΩ resistor will be `I=U/R=0.6/1000=0.6 mA`.

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless to use parallel diode with a resistor having greater resistance because they will have the same voltage drop and much of the current flows through the diode acting like there is no resister at all. What I want to say is the resistance of the resistor should be less than that of the diode to have the same job done and protect the diode from high flowing current.

Comment: It is not meaningless, even if in this context it may seem so. In some cases, it is desirable to have a large current flow in the forward direction, but not totally cut the current off in reverse, which some applications may require. Also, you can know how much current is flowing through the resistor as I=V/R and both V and R are known.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).